# MVC Data model Attributes- Validation on Server or Client Side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating MVC Core project.

I can use either Server side or Client side validation.

Should I conduct Model attribute validations on the Client side? [MSDN Model Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model). Thus, I would convert attributes (example model below) like Required, Length, Display name, etc into Javascript and json, etc. If I use html/javascript client validation, should I just remove the model attributes below?

I read server side is only used for security, and which require access database.
Client side is faster in many cases.

```
public class Movie
{
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Genre { get; set; }

[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }

[StringLength(5)]
public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167452/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-applebook89).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both - MVC gives you both client side and server side validation out of the box when you apply validation attributes.

Server side validation is done by the `ModelBinder` when reading the values from the request, and setting the values of your model properties.

To get client side validation, all you need to do is include the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts in the view.

However, client side validation should only ever be considered a nice bonus - it means you get a client side error message without having to post the data back to the server. However a malicious user can easily bypass client side validation and post back whatever data they want, so its essential that you always implement server side validation.

Typically your POST method should include

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model);
}
.... // save and redirect
```